# ActiveStorage + Simple form + Direct upload create 2 divs instead of 1

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, simple-form, rails-activestorage

I am following this guide to add direct upload using active storage to my rails app:
https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#direct-uploads

I used the exact same code as presented on the website (both CSS and JS).

Everything is clear and seems to be working, but I don't know why it creates 2 identical divs instead of just 1 (as I am uploading 1 file only).

[image]

Later on, as the upload is started, only the first div is affected by JS changes (pending class is removed etc.), while the second is not, just waiting for his turn, that will never come...

Edit: It is `AddEventListener("direct-upload:initialize", (...)` causing the problem, as it fires up twice

Do you know how to overcome this issue?

Edit 2: It is not a perfect solution, but I had put a global variable and even when event listener is being fired up second time, conditional statement stops it from adding another bar...

SOLUTION: It seems, that I have included `direct_uploads.js` twice and that's the result of this action

Comment: How did you managed to implement direct_upload with simple_form ? I'm trying to do it but no luck. If I use form_for it's working fine but with simple_form can't get this work. Perhaps you have some git repo you could share please?

Comment: Try this out:


  `= simple_form_for profile, url: user_profile_path(user) do |f|`  

`.form-group`  

`= f.label :file, label: 'Label for file'`  

`= f.file_field :user_file, multiple: false, direct_upload: true, required: true, data: { max_file_size: 100.megabytes }, input_html: { class: 'file-field' }, class: 'form-control'`   

My dear, formating sucks in comments..
Not sure why I had `:file` in `label` and `:user_file` in `file_field`, try to unify it :) (but it worked that way anyway ;) )

Comment: Hi, thanks for code. Unfortunately this sample doesn't work for me. Following simple form instruction I use   = f.input :film_link, as: :file 
If I use file_field instead upload won't work.  I'll try something else anyway thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't use `f.file_field` with all that comes after it in my example? (I mean `direct_upload` and perhaps `input_html` + `class`? Or you already did?

Comment: I've checked again and you're right changing input from simple form to file_field done the job. Thanks